# Angular - mocking out service method that returns a promise

Tags: angularjs, jasmine

I am trying to test a controller method that relies on a service call to get some data.  The service method returns a promise, and I'd like to test the behavior of the controller if the promise is resolved or rejected.

I have come up with this approach to vary the behavior of my mocked service method, but it does not work.  The `getDataSuccess` flag is always true when the mocked `getData` method is called.  Here's what I have so far:

Controller:

```
app.controller('myController', function($scope, myService) {
       myService.getData()
         .then(function (data) {
             $scope.data = data;                   
         },
         function (data) {
             $scope.serverError = data;
         });
});
```

Test:

```
describe('myController', function () {

    var ctl, serviceMock, getDataSuccess, scope;

    beforeEach(function() {
            getDataSuccess = true;
            serviceMock = {};

        module('app', function ($provide) {
            $provide.value('myService', serviceMock);
        });      

        inject(function ($q) {
            serviceMock.getData = function () {                
                var defer = $q.defer();
                if (getDataSuccess) {
                    defer.resolve("theData");
                } else {
                    defer.reject("theData");
                }
                return defer.promise;
            };
        });
    });

    beforeEach(inject(function ($rootScope, $controller, $httpBackend, myService) {

        scope = $rootScope.$new();

        ctl = $controller('myController', {
            $scope: scope,          
            myService: myService,
        });        
    }));

    describe('myController loading data', function () {

        it('should set $scope.data if data load succeeds', function () {
            getDataSuccess = true;
            scope.$apply();
            expect(scope.data).toEqual("theData");
        });

        it('should set $scope.serverError if data load fails', function () {
            getDataSuccess = false;
            scope.$apply();
            expect(scope.serverError).toEqual("theData");
        });

    });

});
```

Clearly I'm missing something here.  The order of execution is not what I was expecting.  What's the proper way to do this sort of thing?

Here's this example in Plunker:  http://plnkr.co/edit/ODyslivLorjaLM4EqlEF?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

myService.getData function is called where myController is initialized. So if you want to change the behavior getData function by setting getDataSuccess, you need to initialize myController after you set getDataSuccess true/false.

What I recommend is something like this.

In appSpec.js

```
describe('myController', function () {

    var ctl, serviceMock, getDataSuccess, scope;

    beforeEach(function() {
        getDataSuccess = true;
        serviceMock = {};

        module('app', function ($provide) {
            $provide.value('myService', serviceMock);
        });      

        inject(function ($q) {
            serviceMock.getData = function () {                
                var defer = $q.defer();
                if (getDataSuccess) {
                    defer.resolve("theData");
                } else {
                    defer.reject("theData");
                }
                return defer.promise;
            };
        });
    });

    beforeEach(inject(function ($rootScope, $controller, $httpBackend, myService) {
        scope = $rootScope.$new();
//      
//        ctl = $controller('myController', {
//            $scope: scope,          
//            myService: myService,
//        });        
    }));

    describe('myController loading data', function () {

        it('should set $scope.data if data load succeeds', inject(function($controller, myService){
            getDataSuccess = true;
            ctl = $controller('myController', {
                $scope: scope,          
                myService: myService,
            });        
            scope.$apply();
            expect(scope.data).toEqual("theData");
        }));    

        it('should set $scope.serverError if data load fails', inject(function($controller, myService){
            getDataSuccess = false;
            ctl = $controller('myController', {
                $scope: scope,          
                myService: myService,
            });        
            scope.$apply();
            expect(scope.serverError).toEqual("theData");
        }));    

    });

});
```

[This is updated plunker.](http://plnkr.co/edit/L1AbkHCmAIDVOGuBihKd?p=preview)

Comment: Yep, that was the problem all right.  Seems obvious now in hindsight :).  Thanks!